# Show tabular data in table view cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, tabular

How can I add a tabular row like this Android app in an iOS application?  It's the second row with integers.  They need to be centered and equal in width.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

iOS have custom table view cells. Like this:

[image]

You can use this type of cell in your tableview. While populating the table view just add your desired data in these labels. Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: I am doing that but what control are the integers using?  I want them centered and equal in width when expanded.

Comment: expand means orientation change?

Comment: No if viewed in an ipad, the widths are equal.

Comment: @MikeFlynn You are looking for auto layout, which allows you to easily express the layout of your views

Comment: @mikeflynn > Here is a good example of auto layout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights